# How can I identify the start and end of lower period of noisy data?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have noisy data at roughly 1 minute intervals across a day.

Here is a simple version:

[image]

How can I identify the start and end index values of the less noisy and lower valued period marked in yellow?

Here is the test data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arr = np.array([8,9,7,3,6,3,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,2,2,3,2,2,5,7,8,9,15,20,21])

plt.plot(arr)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Define "less noisy".

Comment: I mean the number is staying within a lower band of highs and lows

Comment: Yes, you need to specify in your program what exactly you mean by "lower" - lower than what?

Comment: That's what I was looking for an answer to. How do I define this area. It is obvious by eye.

Comment: Its going to depend on your real data. To get low values, you should find the minimum and allow for some small deviation. In this case, 1 is the smallest and it looks like you want to include values up to 3. Assuming absolute deviation was what mattered for your data, low could mean `arr[i]<=min+2`. For less noisy, a crude check would just be if the values before and/or after it don't change by much, i.e. `math.isclose(arr[i],arr[i+1])`.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what kind of noise you are dealing with? Is Gaussian noise a suitable assumption? Can you assume that the noise is independent of your actual signal of interest? If you could share some more detail about your application scenario it would help to establish what assumption may or may not be valid.

Comment: Are you processing live data as it comes in or collected data in a database/csv ?  What is the data or what is the nature of this data ?

Comment: Do you have only low level noise ?  What about high level noise ?

Answer (score 4):

You could try to detect less noisy points by measuring the variance of the values in their neighborhood.

For example, for each point you can look at the last N values before it and calculate their standard deviation, then flag the point if the std is lower than some threshold.

The following code applies this procedure using the [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html) method of a pandas series.

```
std_thresh = 1
window_len = 5

s = pd.Series([8,9,7,3,6,3,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,2,2,3,2,2,5,7,8,9,15,20,21])

# Create a boolean mask which marks the less noisy points
marked = s.rolling(window=window_len).std() < std_thresh

# Whenever a new point is marked, mark also the other points of the window (see discussion below)
for i in range(window_len + 1, len(marked)):
    if marked[i] and ~marked[i-1]:
        marked[i - (window_len-1) : i] = True
        
plt.plot(s)
plt.scatter(s[marked].index, s[marked], c='orange')
```

[image]

You can try to change the values of `window_len` (the length of the window where you calculate the std) and `std_thresh` (points whose window has std less than it are flagged) and tune them according to your needs.

Note that [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html) considers a window which end at each point, so, whenever you encounter a segment of less noisy points, the first `window_len-1` of them will not be marked. This is why I included the for loop in the code after defining `marked`.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you just want that 'area', you need some way of finding points within certain bounds. How can we do that? Well, we should probably start by finding the minimum of the array and then finding other values in that same array that fall within the specified deviation:

```
def lows(arr, dev=0):
    lim = min(arr) + dev
    pts = []
    for i,e in enumerate(arr):
        if e <= lim:
            pts.append((i,e))
    return pts
```

The above function returns a list of points that fall within the specified bounds. The lower bound is the minimum of the input array and the upper bound is the minimum value plus the deviation you will supply. For example, if you want all points within 1 of the lowest value:

```
plt.plot(arr)
for pt in lows(arr, 1):
    circle = plt.Circle(pt, 0.2, color='g')
    plt.gca().add_patch(circle)
plt.show()
```

[image]